# Prevent assignment rule from running again when queue member works on it

Tags: case, queue, assignment-rules

I have implemented an assignment rule. It is important for this assignment rule to run when a case is created. For this, I have enabled the assignment rule checkbox from page layout properties. Now, When it gets assigned to a queue and a member takes the ownership of the record, when he updates anything, the case gets re-assign to the queue again.

I want to prevent it from running again when a queue member is working on it.

Please suggest possible solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the criteria for your rule entries, set "Run this rule if the" to "formula evaluates to true". Then add "ISNEW()" to the formula (alongside possible other criteria). Do that for all rule entries, then they will only fire when the case is newly created.

Answer (score 0):

We have this same issue.
After adding the isnew() now it assigns the case to the default owner, when we just want is to not re-assign the case.

Comment: I turned off the assignment rule checkbox and now it doesn't change the assignee on edit